# Logarithmic inequality: $\log_{1/3}^2(x^2-3x+2) - \log_{1/3}(x-1)>\log_{1/3}(x-2) +6$

Tags: inequality, logarithms

I need help solving this:

$$\log_{1/3}^2(x^2-3x+2) - \log_{1/3}(x-1)>\log_{1/3}(x-2) +6$$

So far I could not make sense of this, because I don't understand how to handle $\log^2$ or the $+6$  at the end... can someone explain it to me?

Comment: You can bookmark this link for future [MathJax quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\log_{1/3}^2(x^2-3x+2) - \log_{1/3}(x-1)>\log_{1/3}(x-2) +6$$
$$\log_{1/3}^2(x^2-3x+2) - \log_{1/3}(x-1)-\log_{1/3}(x-2) -6 > 0$$
$$\log_{1/3}^2(x^2-3x+2) - \log_{1/3}(x-1)(x-2) -6 > 0$$
$$\log_{1/3}^2(x^2-3x+2) - \log_{1/3}(x^2-3x+2) -6 > 0$$
Now substitute $\log_{1/3}(x^2-3x+2) = t$

Answer (score 2):

Inequallity is equivalent to
\begin{align*}
\log_{1/3}^2(x^2-3x+2)-\left[\log_{1/3}(x-1)+\log_{1/3}(x-2)\right]-6&>0\\
\log_{1/3}^2(x^2-3x+2)-\log_{1/3}(x^2-3x+2)-6&>0\\
\left[\log_{1/3}(x^2-3x+2)-3\right]\left[\log_{1/3}(x^2-3x+2)+2\right]&>0
\end{align*}
This inequallity holds $\iff$ $\log_{1/3}(x^2-3x+2)\in(-\infty,-2)\cup(3,\infty)$ 
\begin{align*}
\iff x^2-3x+2&\in\left(0,\frac{1}{27}\right)\cup\left(9,\infty\right)
\end{align*}
Since $x^2-3x+2=(x-\frac{3}{2})^2-\frac{1}{4}$:
$0< x^2-3x+2<\frac{1}{27}\iff \frac{1}{4}< \left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^2<\frac{31}{108}\iff x\in\left(\frac{27-\sqrt{93}}{18},1\right)\cup\left(2,\frac{27+\sqrt{93}}{18}
\right)$

$x^2-3x+2>9\iff \left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^2>\frac{37}{4}\iff x\in\left(-\infty,\frac{3-\sqrt{37}}{2}\right)\cup\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{37}}{2},\infty
\right)$

Since $\log_{1/3}(x-2)$  is real defined if $x>2$ we have as Solution set: $$\left(2,\frac{27+\sqrt{93}}{18}
\right)\cup\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{37}}{2},\infty
\right).$$

Comment: Check the roots: they aren't $2$ and $3$.

Comment: @egreg Thanks, I have corrected this mistake.